# I have accidentally turned off my password - how do I recover from this?

Tags: password-recovery

I have the following problem with my computer. It's a desktop, 32 bit, originally came with Windows XP, 999.4 MiB of RAM, Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.60GHz x 2, 77.7GB disk space.

1. I accidentally turned off my password, :( so if I need to download something I can't. And I can't put  a diff. OS on here, my USB was missed up by Ubuntu, its a 1Gb USB, and it says there is no room on there "With nothing on it"

If I type su in the terminal, it asks me for my password, I type it in, doesn't work. This was before I changed my password. During the installation I was never asked for a password.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu - we like singular questions that can be answered - I have edited your question as such.  Thanks.

Comment: Ya, Btw I have four questions...

Comment: If you have four questions, post four different questions.  Don't bunch them all together into one, Jonah.

Comment: ty now I know.. :p

Answer (score 0):

Can you use sudo command?

```
sudo <command_to_execute_as_root>
```

If not, you can try enter in the GRUB boot manager. In the Ubuntu option press the "e" key to edit, edit the line "linux    /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-18-generic root=UUID=00aad4d6-a7e5-41ce-a25e-dfda8664bb99 ro   quiet splash" and add in the end:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

This boot machine with bash directly without passwd. The you must remount the root filesystem in read/write mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

And you can execute passwd to change the root passwd. ;)

Comment: :0? put in easier to understand terms, I have a young brain.

Comment: Sorry, is the easiest way to recover lost root password. :(

Comment: It's funny, I look back at all these old questions of mine and think " Huh, I now know how to compute :D " Yeah, it's a joke.